# Why are my files untracked after creating new folders?

Tags: git, github

I am following step 1 of this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@ultravulturekangaroo/fullstack-tddd-mern-app-part-2-57844fca3bab) and created two new folders called `lib` and `test` inside my `backend` folder. My folder structure looks like the following:

```
├── lib
│ ├── json
│ │ ├── messages.json
│ │ └── testMessages.json
│ └── model.js
├── test
│ └── model.test.js
└── package.json
```

After doing `git add .` and `git commit`, I get the following message:

```
Untracked files:
        ../lib/
        ../test/
```

I've made new folders before and this is the first time I'm seeing this message. Why is this error occurring and what can I do to resolve it?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/mern-app)

Comment: This isn't an error; "untracked" just means "git hasn't seen these before".

Comment: Try `git add --all`

Comment: Notice the '..' in the message, that seems to imply the directories exist higher up the path than you are executing the git command in, so a 'git add .' is not going to catch those directories since that executes *from* the directory you are executing the command in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `git add --all`, committed, and pushed which solved the issue.